# upgrade Kubernetes plugin to 1.28.6 break our pipeline flows

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-kubernetes

Jenkins Master : 2.282
Kubernetes plugin 1.28.5

after upgrade Kubernetes to 1.28.6 version , we find out that part of our pipelines  that use yaml from shared library

our shared library yaml

```
agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud "kube-cloud"
            inheritFrom 'jnlp-slave-terraform'
            yaml libraryResource('k8s/tf.yaml')
        }
    }
```

the failed flows use initContainers in the yaml file.
I think this commit break it - [https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/pull/929

attached the error we got when trying to lunch new pods

```
Also:   java.lang.Throwable: launched here
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer._connect(SlaveComputer.java:283)
    at hudson.model.Computer.connect(Computer.java:435)
    at hudson.slaves.CloudRetentionStrategy.start(CloudRetentionStrategy.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.executors.OnceRetentionStrategy.start(OnceRetentionStrategy.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.executors.OnceRetentionStrategy.start(OnceRetentionStrategy.java:46)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputer(AbstractCIBase.java:161)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.access$000(AbstractCIBase.java:43)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase$2.run(AbstractCIBase.java:223)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputerList(AbstractCIBase.java:206)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.updateComputerList(Jenkins.java:1632)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes$2.run(Nodes.java:139)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes.addNode(Nodes.java:135)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.addNode(Jenkins.java:2155)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.lambda$update$6(NodeProvisioner.java:256)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:225)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.access$900(NodeProvisioner.java:64)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker.doRun(NodeProvisioner.java:823)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:91)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

created an issue as well
[issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65074](http://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65074)

Comment: This should be addressed as an [issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65074?filter=10230&jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20kubernetes-plugin%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

Comment: I open an issue as well  https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65074

though someone else find it and has any idea to workraound

Comment: Yes, well it helps all when issues are linked to questions and vuce-versa. Consider updating your descriptions.

Comment: added the link to the question , Thanks